# Arrange Date in a Row to Specific Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an code to generate a report based on a exported excel data from work. Here is the sample data:
[image]

I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

I've tried writing a few code in excel vba but the loop keeps giving me an error. Please take note that I've been only studying code a few weeks. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*. Watch the demonstration for reference. Takes less then **2 minutes** to perform the task.

---

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    UnpivotOtherColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Style"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    SplitColumnsByPosition = Table.SplitColumn(UnpivotOtherColumns, "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 5}), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    PivotColumns = Table.Pivot(SplitColumnsByPosition, List.Distinct(SplitColumnsByPosition[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value"),
    RemovedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(PivotColumns,{"Attribute.2"})
in
    RemovedColumns
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Using `Excel Formulas` without any `Recursive LAMBDA()` helper functions:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, Table1,
     _Style, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _ColSo, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _ColToRows, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(_ColSo,3),2),
     _RowsToRept, INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Style))-1/2)+1,
     _StylesRepeat, TAKE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_Style,IFS(_ColSo<>"",_RowsToRept)),2),2),,1),
     VSTACK({"Style","Color","Soqty"},HSTACK(_StylesRepeat,_ColToRows)))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this function (instead of vba):

```vb
=LET(data,A2:M6,
idx,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
buildStyleλ,LAMBDA(r,LET(d,DROP(FILTER(r,r<>""),,1),
                         CHOOSECOLS(EXPAND(WRAPROWS(d,2),,3,INDEX(r,1,1)),3,1,2))),
DROP(REDUCE("",idx,LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,buildStyleλ(CHOOSEROWS(data,i))))),1)
)
```

`buildStyleλ` takes a single row, removes the style part, then useses `WRAPROWS` to write the color/qty part one below the other.
`EXPAND` and `CHOOSECOLS` are used to place the style to the left of the result.

[image]

Comment: You have a typo `buildStyle?`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you! - λ sign doesn't output when I write the formula to the VBE direct window (necessary as I am working on a German Excel to get the english formula) - fixed it

Comment: My list separator is also a semicolon. I handle this issue with `Excel Labs`. Under `Settings` I unselect the 1st and select the 2nd setting which keeps the formulas in the format of the cell and the list separator is a comma (English) respectively. So I select the cell with the formula and copy it from `Excel Labs` to `SO`. Similarly, I copy a formula from `SO` and paste it into `Excel Labs`. `Excel Labs` is free and you can install it using `Developer->Add-ins->Store` and search for it.

Answer (score 0):

### Transform Data: Wrap to Columns

**Final**

```
=LET(data,A2:M7,rep_cols,1,wrap_cols,2,
    IsRowNotNothing,LAMBDA(data,LEN(REDUCE(EXPAND("",ROWS(data),,""),
        SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),LAMBDA(rr,c,LET(
        r,INDEX(data,,c),rr&IF(r="",""," ")))))>0),
    du,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,(COLUMNS(data)-rep_cols)/wrap_cols),
        TAKE(data,,rep_cols))),
    sd,DROP(data,,rep_cols),
    dd,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(IF(sd="","",sd)),wrap_cols),
    FILTER(HSTACK(du,dd),IsRowNotNothing(dd)))
```

[image]

**Readable (Developer Mode)**

```
=LET(data,A2:M7,rep_cols,1,wrap_cols,2,
    IsRowNotNothing,LAMBDA(data,LEN(REDUCE(EXPAND("",ROWS(data),,""),
        SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),LAMBDA(rr,c,LET(
        r,INDEX(data,,c),rr&IF(r="",""," ")))))>0),
    su,TAKE(data,,rep_cols),
    sd,DROP(data,,rep_cols),
    rcols,(COLUMNS(data)-rep_cols)/wrap_cols,
    du,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,rcols),su)),
    dd,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(IF(sd="","",sd)),wrap_cols),
    f,HSTACK(du,dd),
    i,IsRowNotNothing(dd),
    r,FILTER(f,i),
r)
```

Comment: Here `REDUCE` is used just to concatenate columns with empty strings and spaces. The issue with reduce is when using `VSTACK` (or `HSTACK`) with it. Also, look at Tom Sharpe's [Masterpiece](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835746) where `REDUCE` also isn't an issue.

Comment: Also will it work with `10K` rows of data? I had a same scenario where I used `MAKEARRAY()` found it works more faster. No offence just trying to understand `LAMBDA()` more clearly,

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I think this is the equivalent of what the function is doing: `IsRowNotNothing,LAMBDA(data,BYROW(IF(data="",""," "),CONCAT)>0),`. Is this faster or is there a better way? A test would tell. I'm using this to make the formula flexible so it can be used with `wrap_cols>=2`, not just `=2`.

Comment: Completely understand your logic .